# What is the shape of [Cr(NO)₄]?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, molecular-orbital-theory, crystal-field-theory, ligand-field-theory

I was learning about crystal field theory recently. I am quite confused about predicting the shape of $\ce{[Cr(NO)4]}$ complex because I am not able to conclude whether it will be square planar or tetrahedral.

How to predict the shape of $\ce{[Cr(NO)4]}$ using crystal field theory?

Will $\ce{NO}$ act as a 3-e- donor here?

Will all the four $\ce{NO}$ that are in coordination with $\ce{Cr}$ be of the type nitrosyl or will three of them be nitroso and one nitrosyl (because $\ce{Cr^3+}$ is one of the common oxidation state of $\ce{Cr})?$

Comment: The oxidation state is zero, and not +3. Are you sure that this compound exists ? I have not voted down.

Comment: @Maurice Thanks for answering one part of my question.Yes,I am sure that the compound exists.You can check that here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_nitrosyl_complex

Comment: @Maurice Since the oxidation state is zero and not +3, you mean the shape has to be square planar or tetrahedral?

Comment: $\ce{[Cr(NO)4]}$  is very bad for CF theory. CF works well with complexes with strongly charged components. CO, NO and PR3 complexes do not really fit.

Comment: I quickly googled and found a paper claiming that the system is best viewed as complex of $\ce{Cr^+}$, but actually is very similar (and isoelectronic) to $\ce{Ni(CO)4}$

Comment: $\ce{Ni(CO)}4$ is the obvious analogy, with NO being a 3 electron donor compared to the two electron CO in the Ni case - both leading to 18 electron compounds.

Comment: As per my understanding:
In $\ce{[Ni(CO)4]}$ :Ni in the presence of strong field ligand must have d^10 configuration (due to pairing of e-s).So,in the absence of inner d-orbital,I can understand that $\ce{[Ni(CO)4]}$ has to be tetrahedral
But in $\ce{[Cr(NO)4]}$ : Cr in the presence of strong field ligand must have d^6 configuration (due to pairing of e-s).As dx-y and dx2-y2 orbitals are free,square planar option is still there.Also,NO is a strong field ligand,which means it favours formation of square planar complexes which have have higher crystal field splitting energy.

Comment: @IanBush I don't understand how $\ce{[Ni(CO)4]}$ is the obvious analogy to $\ce{[Cr(NO)4]}$

Comment: Both are 18 electron compounds (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/18-electron_rule). The CO ligands donate 4x2=8 electrons to Ni make 8+10=18. The NO ligands donate 4x3=12 electrons to make 12+6=18. They are therefore isoelectronic. The nickel compound is tetrahedral. So therefore is the Chromium compound.

Comment: Does this mean all isoelectronic compounds are isostructural?If not,when all can that logic be used?

Comment: @permeakra "CO, NO and PR3 complexes do not really fit." This is because CF theory views interaction between metal and ligand as purely ionic right?
I am not getting "the system is best viewed as complex of Cr+"
Does this mean NO- is acting as a ligand here? or is there some electron being pulled by nitrosyl from Cr ?

Comment: @Chem-Learner CF theory was designed for rationalization of optical spectra of ions in aqueous solution. It can make semi-quantitive predicitons for mostly ionic complexes like $\ce{Ti^{3+}}$ aquaions. It works well for the first row of d-elemnt aqueous solutions.

Comment: @Chem-Learner However, once covalent interactions become dominant, purely exlectrostatic considerations, that are the core of CFT, are not sufficient anymore.

Comment: Describing the system in details would be too long, regrettably. I'm not ready for it at the moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on available theoretical considerations and a available literature, a tetrahedral geometry appears to be a good assumption for $\ce{Cr(NO)4}$.

1. The NO ligand can be rendered as a three-electron donor, if we take
   it as uncharged.  It is actually similar to CO, really, in that it
   interacts through its $\pi^*$ orbitals as well as its $\sigma$
   orbital; but NO unlike CO has an electron to offer from its $\pi^*$.
   That plus the $\sigma$ electrons makes three.
2. We then may identify the central metal atom as having 18 valence
   electrons.  When this happens with multiple ligands we typically see
   an arrangement with highest order symmetry, thus tetrahedral for
   four-coordination.  This gives the best possible bonding to the
   entire set of valence orbitals involved in the 18-electron
   structure.  This is seen in the tetrahedral four-coordinationn of
   $\ce{Ni(CO)4}$, and in the octahedral six-coordination of the series
   $\ce{[V(CO)6]^-}$, $\ce{Cr(CO)6}$, $\ce{[Mn(CO)6]+}$, $\ce{[Fe(CO)6]^{2+}}$.  So, we should expect $\ce{Cr(NO)4}$ to be tetrahedral.
3. [Heberhold and  Razavi](https://www.academia.edu/25272323/Tetranitrosylchromium_Cr_NO_4_) found evidence for a tetrahedral structure in $\ce{Cr(NO)4}$ from its IR spectrum.